# Asp.Net Mvc - Html.TextBox - Set Autofocus property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, html-helper

In Html 5, there is a new attribute on textbox called autofocus.

The problem is that it is a boolean value (there or not there)

It should look something like :

```
<input name="a" value="" autofocus>
```

I tried :

```
<%= Html.TextBox( "a", null, new { autofocus } ) %>
```

But, it gives me an error because I'm not setting a value to autofocus...

I know I can do it manually,  but can I do it with Html.TextBox ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try `<%= Html.TextBox( "a", null, new { autofocus = "" } ) %>`

According to the [HTML5 spec on boolean attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#boolean-attribute):

> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the **empty string** or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the **attribute's canonical name**, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

So either

- `<input name="a" value="" autofocus>` or
- `<input name="a" value="" autofocus="">` or
- `<input name="a" value="" autofocus="autofocus">`

should be valid.

Answer (score 3):

As of XHTML, the standard way to enable such a boolean attribute would be:

```
<input name="a" value="" autofocus="autofocus" />
```

therefore, assuming that is still valid in HTML5, you could use the following code:

```
<%=Html.TextBox( "a", null, new { autofocus: "autofocus" } ) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can do following along with some other attributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "class1", @placeholder = "Email", @autofocus = "autofocus" })
```

Note: Only issue with autofocus is that, in IE browsers, placeholder text does not get displayed when the input control is in focus (it's an issue with IE).