# ASP.NET MVC, add single attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

For attribute="value" I use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { type = "email", @class = "form-control",
 placeholder="Email address" })
```

it gives me:

```
<input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email address"
 type="email" value="" />
```

How can I add single attribute to that, so I need required and autofocus:

```
<input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email address" 
type="email" value=""  required autofocus />
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with using `new { required = "required" }`? As far as I know that would be the only way to do it. That won't give you exactly the markup you want but it'll still work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.Net Mvc - Html.TextBox - Set Autofocus property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998247/asp-net-mvc-html-textbox-set-autofocus-property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `string.Empty` you will get an empty attribute in the generated html

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { type = "email", @class = "form-control",
placeholder = "Email address", required = string.Empty, autofocus = string.Empty })
```

Comment: It generates me: autofocus="" and required="", but I need just autofocus required

Comment: @ihorko that's interesting... For me, I get just "required autofocus"

Comment: autofocus="" is still valid.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998247/asp-net-mvc-html-textbox-set-autofocus-property